# Using Glide with GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, android-glide

I'm trying to use Glide for loading custom images to a Google Maps info window. I'm passing the activity context to the adapter (see my code bellow). But I don't see neither images nor errors.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
class GuideMapInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    private final View mWindow;
    private final View mContents;
    private HashMap<Marker, MapPoint> mMarkers;
    private Context mContext;

    GuideMapInfoWindowAdapter(Context context, HashMap<Marker, MapPoint> markerMapPointHashMap) {
        mWindow = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.guide_map_custom_info_window, null);
        mContents = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.guide_map_custom_info_content, null);
        mMarkers = markerMapPointHashMap;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        render(marker, mWindow);
        return mWindow;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        render(marker, mContents);
        return mContents;
    }

    private void render(Marker marker, View view) {
        ImageView mImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge);
        MapPoint mPoint = markers.get(marker);
        String mUrl = UrlBuilder.guidePhoto(mPoint.getGuideId(), mPoint.getPageId(), 100);
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(mUrl)
                .centerCrop()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(mImage);

        String title = marker.getTitle();
        TextView titleUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title));
        if (title != null) {
            titleUi.setText(title);
        } else {
            titleUi.setText("");
        }

        String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
        TextView snippetUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
        if (snippet != null) {
            snippetUi.setText(snippet);
        } else {
            snippetUi.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, you are downloading images asynchronously. After you return `mContents` in `getInfoContents` any changes to imageview will not reflect.

I've updated your render function, haven't tested it though.

```
private void render(Marker marker, View view) {
        ImageView mImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge);
        MapPoint mPoint = markers.get(marker);
        String mUrl = UrlBuilder.guidePhoto(mPoint.getGuideId(), mPoint.getPageId(), 100);
        Bitmap image = Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(mUrl)
                .asBitmap()
                .into(-1,-1)
                .get();
        mImage.setImageBitmap(image);

        String title = marker.getTitle();
        TextView titleUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title));
        if (title != null) {
            titleUi.setText(title);
        } else {
            titleUi.setText("");
        }

        String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
        TextView snippetUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
        if (snippet != null) {
            snippetUi.setText(snippet);
        } else {
            snippetUi.setText("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Asynchronous load will be definitely source of the problem. I replaced the Glide by BitmapFactory and it works. Anyway thanks for your answer, I will return to this and test it.

Comment: Unfortunately .into() has to be used only in background thread, it's not working for my case. I found some examples, where render() method calls itself once again and refresh the view. But for me, the best solution is to preload the images and then load them synchronously as bitmap in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but I found a way to do this.  For my use case, all the pictures are the same size so this worked well for me.

Using the `.override()` with the, `onResourceReady()` and then reloading the InfoWindow loads the images every time.

```
Glide
       .with(Context)
       .load(URL)
       .error(R.drawable.XXXXX)
       .override(150,150)
       .placeholder(R.drawable.XXXXX)
       .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>()
       {
             @Override
             public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) 
             {
                   Log.e("Glide", "Error Loading Image", e);
                   return false; 
             }

             @Override
             public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource)
             {
                   Log.e("Glide", "Image Loaded");
                   if (marker.isInfoWindowShown())
                   {
                         marker.hideInfoWindow();
                         marker.showInfoWindow();
                   }
                   return false;
              }
        })
        .into(Picture);
```